# System.LimitException: Batchable instance is too big: UpdateShippingAddress_Batch

Tags: batch

I am getting the above error when I try to test my scenario which is changing the sales rep name on the salesrepmapping object. My Apex batch class is as follows

```
//global class UpdateShippingAddress_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,Database.AllowsCallouts{
global class UpdateShippingAddress_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>  {  
    List<Shipping_Address__c> shippingList = new List<Shipping_Address__c>();
    List<Shipping_Address__c> updateList = new List<Shipping_Address__c>();

    //global UpdateShippingAddress(List<Shipping_Address__c> shippingAddressList,lIST<Sales_Territory_Mapping__c> SHIPtERRlISTALL)
    global UpdateShippingAddress_Batch (List<Shipping_Address__c> shippingAddressList)
    {           
        shippingList = shippingAddressList;
        system.debug('Updating global class shippingList '+shippingList.size());
    }

    global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        return DataBase.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,ISAL_M_ID__c,ISAL_CS_ID__c,Sales_Rep_CS_Name__c ,Sales_Rep_M_Name__c    FROM Shipping_Address__c WHERE Id IN : shippingList]);        
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Shipping_Address__c> scopeShippingAdress)
    {
         /*for (Integer i=0;i<scopeShippingAdress.size();i++){
             //scopeAcc.get(i).Commercial_Area__c=ownerMap.get(scopeAcc.get(i).OwnerId).Commercial_Area__c;
             updateList.add(scopeShippingAdress.get(i));
         }
         system.debug('Updating global class'+updateList);
         update updateList;*/
         update shippingList;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {}
}
```

I am calling the batch in the Class below

```
public class SalesRepMapping_ShippingAddress {
public static void updatesalesRepMapping(List<Sales_Territory_Mapping__c > salesList,Map<Id,Sales_Territory_Mapping__c > salesNewMap,Map<Id,Sales_Territory_Mapping__c > salesOldMap){     
    system.debug('entering to the class');
    set<String> soldInTerName = new set<String>();  
    List<Sales_Territory_Mapping__c> shipTerr = new List<Sales_Territory_Mapping__c>();
    List<Shipping_Address__c> shipAdd = new List<Shipping_Address__c>();
    List<Shipping_Address__c> finalshipAdd = new List<Shipping_Address__c>();

    for(Sales_Territory_Mapping__c st : salesList){        
        if(st.SoldInTerritoryId__c!=Null && salesOldMap.get(st .id).Sales_Rep__c!=salesNewMap.get(st .id).Sales_Rep__c ){        
            soldInTerName.add(st.SoldinTerritory_Name__c);
            shipTerr.add(st);
        }            
    }
    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Sales_Territory_Mapping__c soldInTerName'+soldInTerName);
    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Sales_Territory_Mapping__c shipTerr'+shipTerr);
    /*
for(Shipping_Address__c sa : [SELECT Id, Name, Territory__c, Sales_Rep_CS_Name__c 
FROM Shipping_Address__c WHERE Territory__c In: soldInTerName]){                                    
shipAdd.add(sa);                              
}*/

    String query='SELECT Id, Name, Territory__c, Sales_Rep_CS_Name__c,Sales_Rep_M_Name__c,ISAL_CS_ID__c,ISAL_M_ID__c    FROM Shipping_Address__c WHERE Territory__c In: soldInTerName limit 50000';
    List<Shipping_Address__c> saList = new List<Shipping_Address__c>();
    saList=Database.query(query);

    for(Shipping_Address__c sa :saList){                                    
        shipAdd.add(sa);                              
    }    
    system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Shipping_Address__c shipAdd'+shipAdd);

    for(Sales_Territory_Mapping__c salesTer : shipTerr){
        for(Shipping_Address__c salesAdd :shipAdd){
            //  salesAdd.Sales_Rep_CS_Name__c = salesTer.Sales_Rep__c ;


            if(salesTer .Role__c=='FSALM'){
                salesAdd .Sales_Rep_M_Name__c = salesTer.Sales_Rep__c;
                //a.AccTerritoryNameM__c = salesRepMapping.SalesTerrMapName__c;
            }

            if(salesTer .Role__c=='FSALCS'){
                salesAdd .Sales_Rep_CS_Name__c = salesTer.Sales_Rep__c;
                //a.AccTerritoryNameCS__c = salesRepMapping.SalesTerrMapName__c;
            }           

            if(salesTer .Role__c=='ISALCS'){
                salesAdd .ISAL_CS_ID__c = salesTer.Sales_Rep__c;
            }

            if(salesTer .Role__c=='ISALM'){
                salesAdd .ISAL_M_ID__c = salesTer.Sales_Rep__c;           
            }

            finalshipAdd.add(salesAdd);
        }       
    }   
    //update finalshipAdd;
    //Database.ExecuteBatch(new UpdateShippingAddress_Batch (shipAdd,shipTerr));
    Database.ExecuteBatch(new UpdateShippingAddress_Batch (finalshipAdd),100);

}
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1) How are you calling this batch class
2) And y r u using Database.getQuerylocator in start ? You can simply have return [soql qurey]

Comment: @pmvsdt: I am using the code in other class. Can I add the class here in the comment box.

Comment: @Harvey Ideally, you should always put all the relevant information/code in your question. You can edit your question and update your problem's description based on feedback or things that you see that can be improved in order to have a better understanding of your question. Save comments for small/quick clarifications.

Comment: Got it, I have edited the question and added the class where I am calling the batch class. Thanks Joca.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely heap size (Even though you are not using stateful.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000239885&language=en_US

> If a batch apex class implements Database.Stateful, the instance state
>   is stored in the database.  At this time we do a check against the
>   size of the instance state and the exception is thrown when the Apex
>   Heap Size limit is exceeded. For synchronous Apex the heap size limit
>   is 6 MB and for asynchronous Apex the limit is 12 MB. This exception
>   can obviously occur in a scenario where large collections are
>   persistently maintained
>
> In some cases Database.Stateful isn't being implemented or the steps
>   above are not helpful in working around this exception. If you've
>   attempted these workarounds and are still seeing this exception,
>   please follow the steps below to find where the heap size is being
>   exceeded.

Now, there is what appears to be un-necessary use of heap size, namely the Lists in the constructor. Try changing to the below and see if it resolves your issue

```
global class UpdateShippingAddress_Batch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

Set<ID> recordIds;

global UpdateShippingAddress_Batch(Set<ID> shippingAddressIds) {
    recordIds = shippingAddressIds;
}

global Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return DataBase.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, ISAL_M_ID__c, ISAL_CS_ID__c, Sales_Rep_CS_Name__c, Sales_Rep_M_Name__c FROM Shipping_Address__c WHERE Id IN :recordIds]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Shipping_Address__c> scopeShippingAdress) {
    //.....Do what you need here.....
    update scope;
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

}

}
```

Now you may need to do additional queries, or pass the records to a separate processing method. Hard to tell what else you need as in your for loop you were getting values from an object not in your code so I do not know how to help you with that part.

You may also find the answer here of use (Your question may be a duplicate of this as well): [batchable instance is too big](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92985/batchable-instance-is-too-big)

Comment: and ... the `global` modifier is unnecessary, `public` will do